# Linear operator norm problem(PNS mathematics)

Tags: linear-algebra

http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/suppl/10.1142/7741/suppl_file/7741_chap01.pdf
[image]
This problem is the qualifying exam problem of the 
"Problems and solutions in mathematics".

And, the part of given solution is as follows.

[image]

In the underlying(red) part, I think that calculution isn't correct. 
Is that correct calculuation?

Comment: well the inequality comes from the fact that a norm must be [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity). the latter part seems to state $q_{11}^2+q_{12}^2+q_{13}^2+\dots+q_{1n}^2=1$ and similarly for the sum of $q_{2k}$, which follows from the fact its columns are unit vectors

Comment: @oldrinb/ Ah. My question is not inequality. In the underlying equality, the indexes of "lambda" are fixed. But, I think that indexes are "i".

Comment: since $x=a_1f_1+a_2f_2=(a_1,a_2,0,\dots)^T$ it follows that $\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\cdot(a_1,a_2,0,\dots)=(\lambda_1a_1,\lambda_2a_2,0,\dots)$ -- the indices should be fixed.

Comment: @oldrinb/  Hmmm......  Can  you explain the exact meaning of this notation        "( , ,  )^T"?

Comment: It denotes the transpose.